# Как прочитать parquet файл на s3?

Tags: sql, select

Есть s3 bucket и на нем лежит файл с разрешением parquet.
On-premises установлен Trino.
Как сделать в trino-cli запрос типа select * from s3a://bucket/file.parquet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ответ на мой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768078/how-read-the-parquet-file-located-on-s3-using-trino)

Методом экспериментов и чтении документации - ответил сам же на свой вопрос.